# Scale up the app on large devices (generic scale)

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I have finished my app and it looks great on phones (regardless of the density). Is there a way (attribute or generic method I can call or some sort of settings) that would just make all the screen elements ( images, buttons and texts) bigger for large screens such as tablets.

I remember one of the tablets (I think TF), had an option to just scale up the whole app to fit the screen. This could be only a feature of that specific company or it could be an attribute set on the app. Perhaps I can achieve the same behavior?

PS: I know some may disagree saying that this may not look good on tablet, not the right way and that specific layouts should be provided for large screens but that's ok. I have considered that and I am ok with my approach. My app target is mainly phones but if it runs on 7 or 10 inch tablet (rarely), I want everything just bigger.

Thank you

Comment: The answer is really "no" unfortunately.  You just have to do different layouts, or, proper "reactive" layouts/design. (It's one of those things they don't tell you about app development, that is far more time consuming than one is led to believe from tutorials.)  Good luck!

Comment: @Fattie So I can't put a "super method" that I can execute after every OnCreate which goes in each view and scale up the width and hight?

Comment: really, in short the answer is sadly no.  it just won't work you know?  I'm sorry  :/